# MYSQL Query 2 Tables, 1 JSON Output

Tags: php, mysql, json

Members Table

```
    +------+-----------+--------+--------------+
    | ID   | emmp id   |username| Is Deleted   |
    +------+-----------+--------+--------------+
    |    1 |      3009 |johnn123|     yes      |
    |    2 |      3005 |bobby133|     no       |
    |    3 |      3015 |adaml542|     no       |
    |    4 |      3999 |admin   |     no       |
    +------+-----------+--------+--------------+
```

Permissions Table

```
   +-------------------+-------------+--------------+
   | permission value  | permission  | is_deleted   |
   +-------------------+-------------+--------------|
   |        5234       |   CanEdit   |      no      | 
   |        2562       |   CanAdd    |      no      |
   |        1523       |  CanDelete  |      no      | 
   |        6356       |   CanView   |      no      |
   +-------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Here is the structure that I have above...

I can request JSON data from both tables individually with the code below. (partial code)

```
<?php 

        $query = " SELECT column_name FROM table_name;  ";

            $result = mysql_query( $query );
                if ( !$result ) {
                    $ErrorMessage  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
                    $ErrorMessage .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
                die( $ErrorMessage );
        }

        $JSON_output = array();
            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
        {

        $JSON_output[] = array('column_name'        => $row['column_name'], 
                                'column_name'       => $row['column_name'],
                            );
        }

header( "Content-Type: application/json" );

    $JSON_output = json_encode($JSON_output);

echo $JSON_output . "";

mysql_close($Connection);
?>
```

However, I am having a difficult time querying from both tables the

query from  Members Table.

```
  "emp_id","username", and filter if "is_deleted" is 'yes' or 'no'.
```

query from `Permissions` table

`"permission_value", "permission_name"`, and filter if `"is_deleted`" is `'yes` or `'no'`

JSON Output = `"permission_name","permission_value","emp_id","username"`

Comment: Where is the part where you query the tables?

Comment: $query = " SELECT column_name FROM table_name;  ";

Comment: I restored the text of your question. It's not appropriate to wipe out your question once it is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $query = "
            SELECT      p.permission_type, 
                        m.empid, 
                        m.name

              FROM      members as m

        INNER JOIN      permissions as p

                ON      p.is_deleted = m.is_deleted
            ";
```

.

```
$JSON_output[] = array('Permission Type'        => $row['permission_type'],
                        'Employee ID'           => $row['empid'], 
                        'Full Name'             => $row['name'],
                    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

0 will cause issues because it means empty or null. you can work your queries on **is_deleted** column with **yes/no** or **y/n** if you want to save some space. this will not cause conflicts.

you can work with numeric values when they are integers 1+.

Comment: Thank you. I will make the adjustments :)

Comment: and you are getting the results now? or its still empty?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

    $query = "
    SELECT p.`permission value`,p.permission, m.emp_id, m.username FROM Members as m
    INNER JOIN Permission as p ON p.is_deleted = m.is_deleted
    ";

        $result = mysql_query( $query );
            if ( !$result ) {
                $ErrorMessage  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
                $ErrorMessage .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
            die( $ErrorMessage );
    }

    $JSON_output = array();
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
       $JSON_output[] = $row;
    }

header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
$JSON_output = json_encode($JSON_output);

echo $JSON_output . "";

mysql_close($Connection);
?>
```

Comment: I am trying to add the two tables together to one JSON output so I can display on a PHP page via Javascript. I then make the appropriate adjustments on the PHP page. Ie; Add a permission to a username etc save/add/delete/edit user etc. then button on submit "save" it sends back to the members table the revised changes/added permissions etc.

Comment: is Red_Acid's answer your question ? Then why you ask me ?

Comment: No, I believe Red_Acid's answer was a statement to change from 0 / 1's to Yes/No. Also just updated my previous comments above your question on red_acid

Comment: If you want to look up in 2 tables. Just use UNION.

Comment: I'm sorry, i just caught your question by the way xD. I have updated my answer, keep in mind for get data from 2 tables use INNER JOIN, hope it helps